# How to increase space between columns?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I just added columnWidthRatio: 1; to my mx|ColumnChart to fatten up my columns a little. But now, there's no space between the X axis and columns, and between the columns themselves, so how do I increase this space?

Comment: -1 since you cannot expect stackoverflow users to solve your problem for you. Try adding some concrete code examples and asking more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis, will try to reformulate the question. Concrete code examples can be found in the link I supplied.

Comment: Yes and the click through exactly defies the principle of stackoverflow. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close , and look at "not constructive"

Comment: Cool - sorry, I didn't know that. Hopefully I've done a better job now :)

Comment: Removed -1 since the question is updated and much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try an AreaSeries with minField : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c6a.html

[image]